# Strange behavior when doing where and order by query in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Background: A large table, 50M+, all column in query is indexed.

when I do a query like this:

```sql
select * from table where A=? order by id DESC limit 10;
```

In statement, A, id are both indexed.
Now confusing things happen:

- the more rows `where` returned, the less time whole sql cost
- the less rows `where` returned, the more time whole sql cost

I have a guess here:  postgres do the `order by` first, and then `where` , so it cost more time to find 10 row in the orderd index when target rowset is small(like find 10 particular sand on beach); opposite， if target rowset is large, it's easy to find the first 10.

Is it right? Or there are some other reason for this?

Final question: How to optimize this situation?

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can either use the index on A to apply the selectivity, then sort on "id" and apply the limit.  Or it can read them already in order using the index on "id", then filter out the ones that meet the A condition until it finds 10 of them.  It will choose the one it thinks is faster, and sometimes it makes the wrong choice.

If you had a multi-column index, on `(A,id)` it could use that one index to do both things, get the selectivity on A and still fetch the already in order by "id", at the same time.

Comment: Amazing!  Works like a charm

Comment: @jjanes . . . I'm just curious if you have a doc reference for reading the sorted data and then filtering.

Comment: This talks about using indexes for providing order, but doesn't say anything specifically about filtering:
 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html.  The filter is 'documented' by a line in the`EXPLAIN` output.  (But the ordering is not, you have to infer it from the lack of a separate sort node)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know PGAdmin? With "explain verbose" before your statement, you can check how the query is executed (meaning the order of the operators). Usually first happens the filter and only afterwards the sorting...